# How to have a key value output

Tags: elixir

I'm working on a solution, I want to add numbers like for example `101` results to `1 + 0 + 1 = 2`, and I want to ouput it as `101, 2`.

I have an array, so it's not working quite right, here's my code so far:

```elixir
numbers = Enum.map(array, fn i -> String.to_integer(i) end)

# Get the sum of the numbers
sum = Enum.map(numbers, fn i -> Integer.digits(i) |> Enum.sum() end)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "not working quite right"? Are you getting an ArgumentError (your strings aren't parseable as integers)? Do you have a list where you're expecting an integer?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get both the number and the sum of its digits, you should return a tuple or a list in the mapping function, like so:

```
sum = Enum.map(nums, fn i -> {i, Integer.digits(i) |> Enum.sum()} end)
```

Now, given a list of strings like `["101", "202"]`, `sum` would be equal to `[{101, 2}, {202, 4}]`.

Answer (score 0):

TGO provided the right solution, I just wanted to point out that you can pipe the operations together for a cleaner function, and if you use the `Stream` instead of `Enum` for the first map, the list will only be lazily enumerated once. You asked for a key value output, so I went for a map instead of a tuple.

```elixir
def sum_digits(list) do
  list
  |> Stream.map(&String.to_integer/1)
  |> Enum.map(fn i -> %{i => i |> Integer.digits() |> Enum.sum()} end)
end
```

Example:

```elixir
iex> Example.sum_digits(["101", "123"])
[%{101 => 2}, %{123 => 6}]
```